# Javascript Chrome Extension Help: Getting user highlighted text on a webpage

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, javascript-objects

I am trying to make a chrome extension that gets text highlighted by a user, and then displays it in my chrome extension, but am unable to figure it out. I checked many other similar stackoverflow questions, but could not find a solution that works for me.

I made a content script and a background script, and I tried to grab the dom of the url and then grab the highlighted text using the background script, and then sending a message to the content script to display it. However, this is not working. The code I tried is below.

```
**webClipper.html:**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Web Clipper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webClipper.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Web Clipper</h1>
    <p id="content"><p>
    <button id="clipButton">Clip Text</button>
    <a href = "index.html"><button id="home-btn"><span class="material-icons">home</span></button></a>    
    <script src="webClipper.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tab) {
    const text = tab[0].contentWindow; // Access the window object
    const selection = text.getSelection();
    const selectedText = selection.toString();
  
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ data: selectedText });
  });


**webClipper.js:**

let selectedText = '';
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
  selectedText = message.data;
  const contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');

  if (selectedText.length > 0) {
    contentDiv.textContent = selectedText;
  } else {
    contentDiv.textContent = 'No text highlighted for clipping.';
  }
});

**background.js**:

document.getElementById('clipButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (selectedText.length > 0) {
    alert(selectedText);
  } else {
    alert('No text highlighted for clipping.');
  }
});

**manifest.json:**

{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "version": "1.0",
    "name": "ListMaster",
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "index.html",
      "default_icon": "listmasterlogo.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "tabs",
      "background",
      "content_scripts",
      "file_access"
    ],

    "background": {
       "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["webClipper.js"]
      }]
  }
```

Unsure on what to do, any help would be greatly appreciated!